# MySQL query to display employees who are not managers?

Tags: mysql

I have a working MySQL query that gets "Managers Only" from my tblUsers:

```
SELECT COUNT(e.username) AS employeeCount,
  m.username             AS reports_to,
  m.id
FROM tblusers e
INNER JOIN tblusers m
ON e.reportsToID = m.ID
GROUP BY m.username
```

But I need another query that just gets "Employees Only"?

Comment: Not much to go on here. Please post the sample data with expected output.

Comment: What would be the value of `reportsToID` for someone who is NOT an employee?

Comment: what about this one
`select username from tblusers where id not in (select reportsToID from tblusers)`

Comment: Great. Write one.

Comment: reportsToID is 0 (if an employee only)

Comment: @jlig -- If we can tell that a non-employee would always have `reportsToID=0`, then you can just add this condition `reportsToID<>0` to the `WHERE` clause and you can get all employees.   See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to all, especially @crai

Your query worked fine:

```
    SELECT username, id, reportstoID 
FROM tblusers 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT reportsToID FROM tblusers) AND reportstoID <> '0'
ORDER BY username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  username
  , id
  , reportsToID
FROM 
  tblusers e
WHERE
  e.reportsToID<>0
ORDER BY username
```